# Error 404 Not Found Minify

Tags: javascript, minify, path-combine

I try using minify version 2.1.3(old), because last version not working, when i try combine 3 js and refresh website, it's write 404 not found, i already try follow instruction from this youtube [[ Minify ] Improving Performance - Part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9Ou1pSFJSY)  but still not working.

location ex: C:xampp/htdocs/test/index.php.

location ex: C:xampp/htdocs/test/jquery-1.8.3.min.js.

location ex: C:xampp/htdocs/test/jquery-1.9.1.min.js.

location ex: C:xampp/htdocs/test/jquery-1.9.1.js.

and JS from : localhost/minify/builder/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/min/b=test&amp;f=jquery-1.8.3.min.js,jquery-1.9.1.js,jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

already try change the src to `"/test/min/b=test&amp;f=jquery-1.8.3.min.js,jquery-1.9.1.js,jquery-1.9.1.min.js"`

404 not found it's write when i check the source code shift+ctrl +i same like this video(youtube start in 5:08)

```
Failed to  http://localhost/test/min/b=test&f=jquery-1.8.3.min.js,jquery-1.9.1.js,jquery-1.9.1.min.js  the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

anyone know what wrong? thank you